# Proving a lower bound and upper bound?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I understand why the empty set is a lower bound and A is an upper bound. The only problem I am having is putting my thoughts into a mathematical solution. Can anyone help out? Thanks.

Let A be a set and F ⊆ P(A) be a family of subsets of A. Prove that ∅ is a lower bound for (F;⊆) and that A is an upper bound. What is its greatest lower bound? What is its least upper bound?

(F;⊆) is F with the order ⊆.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a lower bound because $\emptyset\subseteq X$ for every $X\in P(A)$.

Comment: $A$ is an upper bound because $X \subseteq A$ for every $X \in P(A)$.

Comment: The notation $(F; \subseteq)$ suggest that we consider $F$ as an ordered set in its own right, but then $\emptyset$ or $A$ need not be in it? Or are you working with the poset $(P(A),\subseteq)$ and consider $F$ as a subset of that? This would make more sense, given the question.

Comment: It's an abuse of notation. It really means 'Prove that the empty set is a lower bound for F under the subset relation'

Answer (score 1):

In this context you can think of a lower and upper bound in the same way that you would for a subset of the real numbers, i.e. $M$ is an upper bound for the set $A $ if for every $a \in A $, $M\geq a $. All we are doing is swapping the relation $\geq $ for $\subseteq $.

So for the subset relation, we have that $M$ is an upper bound for $F$ if for every $L\in F$, we have $L\subseteq M $. Since the power set of $A$ is just all the possible subsets of $A$, we have that for any $L\in F$, $L\subseteq A $.

Now for the empty set, it is vacuously true that it is a subset of every set. Therefore it satisfies $\emptyset \subseteq L $ for any $L\in F $, and analogously to the example I gave above, it is consequently a lower bound for $F $.